# Get product data between 2 dates using filters in get product rest API magento2

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api

I am using this API to get products between given end_date

> "http://localhost/test/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=end_date&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2019-07-22
>   00:00:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=end_date&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2019-07-22
>   00:00:00&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=lteq"

but it is not giving me correct response. I am getting response like this

```
"{
    "items": [],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "end_date",
                        "value": "2019-07-22 00:00:00",
                        "condition_type": "lteq"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "total_count": 0
}"
```

seems like API considering only last filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
http://localhost/test/rest/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2019-07-22 00:00:00&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=created_at&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=to&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=2019-07-23 23:59:59
```

**I hope this will help**